# pass a password to sudo su

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, remote-access, sudo

I wanted to sudo to different user after ssh'ing into remote server, for this i tried the following:

```
cat remote-test.sh
ssh -t -t abcuser@test-server.net 'bash -s' << EOF
  /tmp/test.sh
EOF
```

when i execute the remote-test.sh from development-server.net, I wanted to ssh to test-server.net as abcuser and then sudo as xyzuser .

```
cat /tmp/test.sh

echo "password" | sudo -S su - xyzuser
cd /tmp/some/directory
```

Can someone please advice how to pass a password while doing sudo su in a script.

Comment: With sudo-privileges, the command is executed as root; `sudo su [username]` shouldn't require a password. It would be the same as, while logged in as root, running `su [username]`.

Comment: as i may see you don't want to grant remote access to `xyzuser`. But what you're trying achieve is a bad practice.

Comment: @newfurniturey you do get prompted for password when doing `sudo command`

Comment: @ant it depends on the sudo config, of course... Perhaps you should just configure sudo to allow the remote user to run that one command as the other user with NOPASSWD. See `man sudoers` for details.

Comment: @FatalError true story, I was referring to the default behavior (should have mentioned that perhaps).

Comment: any idea how to sudo to remote user(xyzuser) after i ssh as abcuser by passing the password along with the sudo command.

Comment: @phani, Hi. Did you find out the solution for this? Thank you in advance for responding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You setup [password-less ssh](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152) to localhost as user `xyzuser` for `abcuser` to achieve what you're trying. You'll need to add `abcuser`'s public key as an authorized_key for `xyzuser`.

Then when you're logged in as `abcuser`, you can do:

```
ssh xyzuser@localhost do_something_as_xyzuser
```

If you've blocked ssh access to `xyzuser`, allow it only through loopback. If you're on linux, see your `/etc/security/access.conf` or equivalent on how to do that.

Comment: so you are basically suggesting to use private key.

Comment: Yes, that's what he's suggesting.  Allowing your initial user to ssh directly to xyzuser@test-server.net via a pre-authorised keypair is a great deal less insecure than embedding passwords in scripts and trying to pass them to `sudo`.

Comment: OP does not have problems with accessing the server remotely, but needs to raise privileges *after* logging in.

Comment: @pkhamre, am just looking at the end goal.

Answer (score 2):

Drop using `su` and configure sudo with the correct permissions. That involves editing `/etc/sudoers` and adding entry for allowing a user to execute a command without providing a password.

You could either make it a bit advanced

```
User_Alias SCRIPT_USER johndoe
Cmnd_Alias SCRIPT_PATH /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

SCRIPT_USER ALL = NOPASSWD: SCRIPT_PATH
```

Or acquire the same thing with a single line.

```
johndoe ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
```

Comment: I wonder why is it not taking this command:
`echo "password" | sudo -S su - xyzuser`

Answer (score 1):

I *highly* suggest that you use the solution proposed by @pkhamre (properly configured sudoers file).  It is the best option, and gives the administrator maximum control.

If that is not achievable then I suggest that you use the solution of @skjaidev (ssh authorized_keys).  This does not require you to have admin permissions, only access to both accounts, so may be suitable for more cases.

But if for some reason ***neither*** of those solutions works for you...

Then you want to use [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) for this. It's probably already on your machine. It's the standard tool for any kind of interactive command-line automation.